# Passing Model into the View in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, model, controller, http-status-code-415

I get a 415 status when I pass my model as an argument. The error says "title": "Unsupported Media Type", "status":415. Here is how I am passing in the model

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/Home")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Home(bookModel model)
{
  //do something
  return View(model);
}
```

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: The [HTTP 415 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415) response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format. The format problem might be due to the request's indicated Content-Type or Content-Encoding, or as a result of inspecting the data directly. So, please check whether you are using the invalid content type. Besides, how do you post model to the controller (using JQuery ajax or submit the form) and show the view, can you share the related code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT is it possible that I am getting the error when I post because of the form element in my view? I followed Microsoft Documentation with uploading files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#upload-small-files-with-buffered-model-binding-to-physical-storage

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

Comment: from the document, in MVC, we could add file control (such as: `<input type="file" name="battlePlans" multiple>` ) in the view, then, using the IFormFile arguments  (like this: `public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> battlePlans) `) to receive the upload file, I have tested it on my MVC application, it works well on my side, please check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swFTw.gif). So, I think the issue is not related to the `enctype` property. Can you post the related code to reproduce the problem, then, I can test it on my side and try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change your code like below, the problem will solve.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Home([FromBody] bookModel model)
```